How to stop Excel to check link before opening?
I have a excel sheet with many shopping sites, most of them are opening without any problem, but some showing error.
for example, "https://zbotic.in/" this is one of the link that excel refuse to open. showing,
issue image
But when I copy the link & paste on browser the link working just fine.
Tried How do I stop Excel from checking the validity of hyperlinks before it opens them? (not solved for me)
Tried these solutions: (but all failed)
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Internet /v ForceShellExecute /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Common\Internet /v ForceShellExecute /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Internet /v ForceShellExecute /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Internet /v ForceShellExecute /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common /v DisableHyperlinkWarning /t REG_DWORD /d 1

To be Honest & to the point, I want MS Excel to open any link to the browser (even a dead links) and not check it before open it to browser, Just like MS Word do.
Is this simple task possible...?
